# how to download and install local package with rudder

Tags: rudder

In "download a file"

URL to download file from [text] http://get.code-industry.net/public/master-pdf-editor-4.0.40_qt5.amd64.deb

Absolute path to download file to on a node [text] /opt/packages/

I also tried

Absolute path to download file to on a node [text] /opt/packages/master-pdf-editor-4.0.40_qt5.amd64.deb

Because the manual curl below works fine.

## curl http://get.code-industry.net/public/master-pdf-editor-4.0.40_qt5.amd64.deb >> /opt/packages/master-pdf-editor-4.0.40_qt5.amd64.deb

Anyone now where I'm going wrong?
I also tried to use rudder to install the manually downloaded .deb without luck.

[1.0] Package Manager has

Package name (or path) [text] /opt/packages/master-pdf-editor-4.0.40_qt5.amd64.deb

Package state  Present

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it working.

1. Full download path including filename.
2. Patience (or manually update agent)
3. Install deps, could not get to install with post install dep fix.
4. Profit

Answer (score 2):

### File download

In the `file_download` generic method, you need to specify the full destination path (here, `/opt/packages/master-pdf-editor-4.0.40_qt5.amd64.deb`). You also need to make sure the destination directory exists, for example with a `directory_create` on `/opt/packages`.

If the download fails, you can troubleshoot it using the `rudder agent run -i` command to display the curl command being used. You can then run it without -the `-s` option to see the error message.

### Package Installation

Package installation from a local file uses `dpkg -i` to install the package, which seems to return an error in you case. You can try installing the package manually (with `dpkg -i master-pdf-editor-4.0.40_qt5.amd64.deb`) to see more precise error messages, but it likely a dependency problem. In this case, you have two options:

- The safest is to install dependencies (using `package_present` with packages from existing repositories) before installing the package you downloaded
- You could also run `apt-get --yes --fix-broken install` after installation, which should help you install missing dependencies

Comment: Hi, I started testing again this morning. Didn't make any changes and it downloaded the package. Maybe I just skipped #rudder agent update but It still will not install. I had set #apt -fy install  as a postscript but for testing purposed I manually installed the missing dependencies on my test unit. The install still fails. the errors i receive are in the following comments

Comment: E| compliant     downloadFile              Permissions (on UNIX sys| http://get.code-i| The permissions on file http://get.code-industry.net/public/master-pdf-editor-4.0.40_qt5.amd64.deb are ok. Skipping ...
rudder     info: Some error occurred while communicating with package module while installing package.
   error: Error installing package '/opt/packages/master-pdf-editor-4.0.40_qt5.amd64.deb'
R: [ERROR] Promise could not be repaired, error encountered:

Comment: Presence of package /opt/packages/master-pdf-editor-4.0.40_qt5.amd64.deb in any version
   error: Method 'package_state' failed in some repairs
E| error         packageManagement         Package                   /opt/packages/mas| Presence of package /opt/packages/master-pdf-editor-4.0.40_qt5.amd64.deb in any version could not be repaired
E| n/a           packageManagement         Post-modification script  /opt/packages/mas| No post-modification script was set to run
   error: Method 'package_management' failed in some repairs

Comment: Ended up re imaging my test machine as I needed it for deployment. For giggles I tried again and it worked.